# How to politely postpone accepting an offer while expecting another?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, contracts

What is the most professional and courteous way to ask for more time before signing an employment contract?

I have applied to Company A and Company B. Company A was first, but Company B is my preference.

It is possible I may accept an offer Company A makes. While the offer has not been made yet, the indication is that the main thing left to do is the paperwork.

Meanwhile I am still waiting for a reply from Company B, and hoping to get a second interview and then an offer. I don't want to start off on the wrong foot with Company A, especially since they are *more* of a sure thing than B at this point.

**What is the best way to ask for more time, and should I mention the other *potential* offer?**

Thanks.

Comment: "While the offer has not been made yet..." - Does this mean that, presently, no company has made an offer yet?

Answer (score 2):

Wait until AFTER you have the offer BEFORE you ask for more time to make up your mind. You don't need to go into details of why and wherefore. Just ask for time to consider their offer politely.

That's really about all you can do, the risk is they need someone quicker, but otherwise it should be fine.